# Rails 3 - Using link_to but adding a # for AJAX Deep Linking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Currently my links in Rails are using link_to as follows:

```
<%= link_to project.name, project %>
```

Which makes something like: `<a href="/projects/1">Project 1</a>`

I'm working to implement an AJAX app with deep linking so instead of the above, I want the output to be (with a #): `<a href="#/projects/1">Project 1</a>`

Is there a way to get this to work with link_to? Or do I need some type of custom helper so I can use something like `link_deep_to`

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I recommend instead of `<a href="#/projects/1">Project 1</a>` to have

```
<a href="/projects/1" class="deep_linker">Project 1</a>
```

And then use jQuery to attach to all links with class of deep_linker. That way your javascript is unobtrusive.

Comment: Hmm that's interesting... Whats wrong with doing this in Rails? Also, won't that be a huge performance hit on the client's browser?

Comment: No, you won't notice the hit for jQuery to select "a.deep_linker" and then attaching to its click event. There's nothing "wrong" with doing what you've said, but it guarantees that it won't work in a non-ajax environment.

Comment: Shoot. so I'm using jQuery BBQ for deep linking and this won't play nicely with that plugin.... so any solutions for making a link_deep_to in rails? So type of helper? I agree that it's not good for non-ajax env, but I know very few of those. And my app isn't to be crawled by google. I also don't want to overbuild so early?